# Why fetch POST returns pending for the API call in React

Tags: php, reactjs

I am trying to create a reactions button to post / retrieve data from the server.
I have did the post and retrieve, but the issue is that whenever I post, if I check developer tools, it says PENDING for the api call. If i refresh the page, I get the new data.

Here is my post:

```
getId = async(reaction) => {

      let eSlug = this.state.slug;

      let data = {
          reactiond: reaction,
          eSlugd: eSlug
      }
      
        await fetch("http://localhost:9000/react/",
        {
            method: "post",
            headers: { 
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
          });
  }
```

My reaction render:

```
<div className="row">
            <div className="col-all">
              <button className="emoji-static">
                <span className="emoji-like">Like</span>
                <span className="emoji-container">
                  <span className="emoji cool zoom" onClick={this.getId.bind(null,"1")}>
                    <img className="svg" src="/img/svg/cool.svg" alt="Cool" />
                    <span className="counter">{this.state.coolReaction}</span>
                  </span>
                  <span className="emoji love zoom" onClick={this.getId.bind(null,"2")}>
                    <img className="svg" src="/img/svg/love.svg" alt="Love" />
                    <span className="counter">{this.state.loveReaction}</span>
                  </span>
                  <span className="emoji laugh zoom" onClick={this.getId.bind(null,"3")}>
                    <img className="svg" src="/img/svg/laugh.svg" alt="Laugh" />
                    <span className="counter">{this.state.laughReaction}</span>
                  </span>
                  <span className="emoji sad zoom" onClick={this.getId.bind(null,"4")}>
                    <img className="svg" src="/img/svg/sad.svg" alt="Sad" />
                    <span className="counter">{this.state.sadReaction}</span>
                  </span>
                  <span className="emoji zoom" onClick={this.getId.bind(null,"5")}>
                    <img className="svg" src="/img/svg/angry.svg" alt="Angry" />
                    <span className="counter">{this.state.angryReaction}</span>
                  </span>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I do not understand why is it stuck in pending and because of this, I do not get anything for console.log
Can you point me in the right direction? I am a complete beginner in React, coming from PHP.

Comment: does the post hit the controller? does the controller return a response? any server side errors?

Comment: Hello @Rok Sprogar , the post reaches the server because if I refresh the front-end page, I get the output of the data reached the database, the reaction output is incrementing. Is just like it is not refreshing, stays in pending. No server side errors. No response receive, F12 in Chrome says the api call is in pending.

Comment: I'd try the same post in POSTMAN to see if I get anything (weird) back...I also see that you're posting to port 9000...so I presume you're loading the site via the same port as well?

Comment: Hi Rok, the backend in node+express is on port 9000 and the front end in react is in 3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly believe the bug here is because of the wrong use of **async/await** and **promises**

**Things to keep in mind when working with promises**

- Use promises whenever you are using `synchronous` or `blocking code`.
- Make sure to write both `.catch` and `.then` methods for all the promises.
- If something is to be done after everything use `.finally`
- The return type of all the methods in the Promise object, regardless of whether they are static methods or prototype methods, is again a `Promise.`

**Things to keep in mind when working with Async/Await**

- async functions return a promise.
- async functions use an implicit Promise to return results. Even if you don’t return a `promise` explicitly, the `async` function makes sure that your code is passed through a promise.
- `await` blocks the code execution within the `async` function, of which `await statement` is a part.
- `await` statements can be overloaded in one `async` function

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I am trying to go over it but it is hard to follow since I am coming from PHP. Do you have a general example ? Not necessarily based on my code, it can be a random example from codepen.

Comment: I would have advise you maybe get a YouTube video that teaches ```promises``` and also teaches ```async/await```... But in basic terms for you to understand is when you ```async/await``` **do not** use promises and when using ```promises``` do not use ```async/await``` choose one between the two

Comment: The issue was that I was not returning anything from the backend when the post was made, I have fixed that and everything is working fine now. Thank you for the explanation, will try and learn more in the future.